# nodejs .map() on loaded content

Tags: php, node.js, request

I have the following sample code (i am completely new to nodejs) , the code is as follow :

```
var http = require('http');
  var fetchurl = 'http://localhost/sampledata.php';
  http.get(fetchurl, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var Response = body;

        Response.map(function(ent,i){console.log(ent.name);});
        console.log("Got response: ", Response.toString());
    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
      console.log("Got error: ", e);
});
```

The above code loads some data from sampledata.php file which is as follow:

```
[{ name : 'david' , age : '25' } , { name : 'Henry' , age : '22' },{ name : 'Tom' , age : '15' },{ name : 'salena' , age : '35' }];
```

The problem is that when i run the top code , i get the error :

```
Type Error: Object (name: 'david', age:'25') has no method `map`
```

But the console log displays the data well, also if i use the same data without loading it from URL, it works perfectly fine.

Whats wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the body to JSON first.

I normally have a function like the following to catch any errors:

```
function tryParseJson(str) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (ex) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then change your line to this:

```
    var Response = tryParseJson(body);
```

Comment: Can you add a console.log("body is %j", body) right before the map call.  I am guessing 'body' is not really an array.

Comment: i have done so , the log is :

body is 

[{ name : 'david' , age : '25' } , { name : 'Henry' , age : '22' },{ name : 'Jay' , age : '35' },{ name : 'matt' , age : '45' },{ name : 'self' ,age : 'testing'];